# Journey Builder error "CurrentlyWaitingInSameInteraction"

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

[image: in]
I have a journey for an abandon basket campaign that was running fine for a long time.

Today I realized that from the 16th stage one of the campaign has stopped sending.

I looked at the history log and the error status is "CurrentlyWaitingInSameInteraction"

Looked up on google and it seems that the contact already entered this journey and is in a wait period.

I haven't changed anything to the journey or any DE that are used in the journey so I'm a bit confused where to look and what to check. Everything seems to be fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: We might need some more information about the journey activities here such as is there a wait activity where the contact is stuck at present. Also, as per the screenshot, it looks that the email send has failed for this contact. Does the email have ampscript/personalization which failed at run time and hence email wasn't triggered? You have most likely set the entry criteria as No-reentry/ re-entry only after exiting and therefore, the contact is unable to enter the journey again. But as I mentioned, some more details about your journey structure would be helpful to dig deeper.